# How does one clear or remove a global in julia?

Tags: global-variables, global, julia

Is there any syntax that does something similar to MATLAB's "clear" i.e. if I have a global variable "a". How do I get rid of it? How do I do the analog of

```
clear a
```

Answer (score 13):

See the latest answer to this question here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-delete-an-object-in-memory%3F

Retrieved from the docs:

> Julia does not have an analog of MATLAB’s clear function; once a name
> is defined in a Julia session (technically, in module Main), it is
> always present.
>
> If memory usage is your concern, you can always replace objects with
> ones that consume less memory. For example, if A is a gigabyte-sized
> array that you no longer need, you can free the memory with A = 0. The
> memory will be released the next time the garbage collector runs; you
> can force this to happen with gc().

Comment: The above link is broken.

Answer (score 13):

## Julia 0.6 < 1.0

In Julia 0.6. You can remove the variable and free up it's memory by calling `clear!()`.

You have to call clear! on the symbolic name of the variable:

```
julia> x = 5
5

julia> sizeof(x)
8

julia> clear!(:x)

julia> sizeof(x)
0
```

As DFN pointed out, this won't actually remove the objects but set them to `nothing`. This is useful for freeing up memory from you workspace as you can "delete" the memory footprint for non-constant objects.

---

## Julia 1.0+

This does not work in Julia 1.0+. If you are using 1.0+ you will have to set the object to `Nothing` and let the garbage collector take it from there.
This is from the official docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-delete-an-object-in-memory?-1).

Comment: This is interesting, but unfortunately it's not completely cleared. The value is simply set to `nothing`. For example, you cannot do `julia> const x = 3`, because then you get `ERROR: cannot declare x constant; it already has a value`.

Comment: Fair enough. I stiff found this useful to free up some memory from non constant objects.

Comment: It's absolutely useful, and, I guess, as close to an official solution that there is. It just has this weakness. And it was new to me:)

Comment: I am getting `ERROR: UndefVarError: clear! not defined` in Julia 1.4.2

Comment: It's interesting that you set it to the type `Nothing` instead of the singleton instance `nothing`, do you have any particular reason for doing so?

Answer (score 10):

As of 0.3.9, it's possible to clear all global variables (get a new workspace), through the workspace() function.

It's also possible to get the variables from the last workspace by using LastMain (e.g. LastMain.foobar).

So currently the only way of doing what you desire, is to clear everything and transfer everything but the variable you want to your new workspace.

Answer (score 9):

Currently, one doesn't. There is, however, an issue to track that feature:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2385

Comment: How about ``exit()`` in the Atom/Juno REPL, any problems with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For **Julia-0.6.4**,

```
clear!(:x)
```

is working as mentioned by @niczky AND it's working in iJulia.

However, for **Julia-1.0.0**,

```
clear!(:x)
```

... throws up the following:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: clear! not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

So, it's broken for Julia-1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely *clear!(:x)* does not work with julia 0.6.0 in notebook(IJulia)! You may choose to use  *x = 0* as an alternative.